# Run AWS CLI KMS encrypt commands from Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cli, amazon-kms

I have 2 cloudformation templates - one that creates a kms key and the other template uses the kms key to encrypt a env variable used in the lambda function.

I wanted to know if there is a way to run the kms encrypt command from within the cloudformation as a prior step and then use the encrypted text for the environment variable while creating the lambda function.

```
aws kms encrypt --key-id <key-id-output-from-stack1> --plaintext fileb://file.txt --query CiphertextBlob --output text > fileoutput.txt
```

This command outputs the encrypted text and I would need to use this text in the lambda function for one of the environment variables as below.

```
GTMLambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: s3://test.google.com/lambdas/09yu567943879
      Handler: src/lambda.handler
      FunctionName: !Ref GTMLambdaFunctionName
      Runtime: nodejs10.x
      MemorySize: !Ref GTMLambdaMemorySize
      Timeout: !Ref GTMLambdaTimeout
      AutoPublishAlias: prod
      Role: !GetAtt GTMLambdaRole.Arn
      KmsKeyArn: !ImportValue GTMKMSKeyArn
      Environment:
        Variables:
          url: >-
            **{insert encrypted text}**
          tbl_prefix: gtm-
```

If this is not possible is there any recommendations on how to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a custom resource for this. It will execute a Lambda function that will encrypt and return the value. That value can then be used in the environment variable.

Something like the following. Make sure to have a resource/parameter/output called `KeyId` with the KMS key id.

```
Resources:
  EncryptEnvRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Action: sts:AssumeRole
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: lambda.amazonaws.com
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: DescribeImages
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
              - Action: kms:Encrypt
                Effect: Allow
                Resource: "*"
  EncryptEnvFunction:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Runtime: python3.6
      Handler: index.handler
      Role: !Sub ${EncryptEnvRole.Arn}
      Timeout: 60
      Code:
        ZipFile:
          Fn::Sub: |
            import base64
            import boto3
            import cfnresponse
            import traceback

            def handler(event, context):
              try:
                t = event['ResourceProperties']['Value']
                k = event['ResourceProperties']['KeyId']
                v = base64.b64encode(boto3.client('kms').encrypt(KeyId=k, Plaintext=t.encode('utf-8'))['CiphertextBlob']).decode('utf-8')

                cfnresponse.send(event, context, cfnresponse.SUCCESS, {}, v)
              except:
                traceback.print_last()
                cfnresponse.send(event, context, cfnresponse.FAIL, {}, 'ok')
  EncryptedEnv:
    Type: Custom::EncryptEnv
    Properties:
      ServiceToken: !Sub ${EncryptEnvFunction.Arn}
      Value: "hello world"
      KeyId: !ImportValue KeyId
  GTMLambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: s3://test.google.com/lambdas/09yu567943879
      Handler: src/lambda.handler
      FunctionName: !Ref GTMLambdaFunctionName
      Runtime: nodejs10.x
      MemorySize: !Ref GTMLambdaMemorySize
      Timeout: !Ref GTMLambdaTimeout
      AutoPublishAlias: prod
      Role: !GetAtt GTMLambdaRole.Arn
      KmsKeyArn: !ImportValue GTMKMSKeyArn
      Environment:
        Variables:
          url: !Ref EncryptedEnv
          tbl_prefix: gtm-
```

Comment: If KeyId is an output from another stack how should it be used inside the lambda function? Should it be used with `.encrypt(KeyId='${!ImportValue KeyId}` ?

Comment: Probably the easiest way would be passing it as a parameter to the custom resource along with `Value` and read it as `event['ResourceProperties']['KeyId']` in the function.

Comment: Thank you. I tried executing this - getting the following error `no last exception: ValueError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/index.py", line 11, in handler
    traceback.print_last()
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/traceback.py", line 173, in print_last
    raise ValueError("no last exception")
ValueError: no last exception`

Comment: Double check your indentation. Seems like `traceback.print_last()` is called outside of the `except` block. Can also just replace it with `raise` and move it below the next line.

Comment: Not that I know. Just delete it again and it should ask you to skip it.

Comment: So I was able to narrow down the issue. Added a `raise Exception(error)` and it returned `'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfe in position 5: invalid start byte: `. Any idea what would cause this. My `Value` is a url in the format `https://abcd:xyz12@34:9876`

Comment: I updated it to base64 the cipher. If it still doesn't work, try just that one line outside of lambda until it works.